# Folder copy method with credentials that shows the current file being copied

Tags: c#, wmi, directory, .net, copying

As the title says, i'm looking for a method or class that will copy a folder remotely from one computer to another. I would also like to show the current file that is being copied in a label as well. Is there a way to have System.IO use credentials and also display the current file name ? I tried WMI but i'm attempting to save the file on a shared drive and WMI from what i read cannot do that. Thanks !

Comment: I assume you are using windows shares to access the remote file system?

You will need to do the following:
1. Map a network share (using the credentials)
2. Iterate over files to copy (to get current name)
3. Copy file to remote location
4. Remove network share.
 

All the pieces are available in the .net libraries. Post what you have so far if you would like more specific help

Comment: As a hint: [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms143327.aspx)